# calling static function in super class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

2 classes named base and derived contains methods
like

```
   interface class base:NSObject{
     +(int)getmaxrow{
     return 30;
    }
    +display{
   print [getmaxrow]; ///here is the :( how to call getmaxrow so 
                     ///that it should wrk     perfectly on derived aswell as base  
   }
    }
   interface class derived: base{
   +(int)getmaxrow{
    return 45;
   }
   }
```

here we need a proper method to call from derived so that it should work th overrided method

Comment: Maybe `[self doStuff];`?

Comment: self cant work on static methods

Comment: @user1844112, maybe not in this language, what ever it is. but in objective-c it can.

Comment: @user1844112 What are you even talking about? Why do you assume (it's wrong anyways) that it can't?

Comment: this code looks like a textbook of Objectve-C and one about Java were used in a Confetti-Parade. After that parade someone tried to reconstruct them.

Comment: @H2CO3 how can i get the derived class method called in super

Comment: @H2CO3 ? is simple how a derived class method gets called in super class

Comment: @user1844112 `[super doStuff];`

Comment: @H2CO3 super is not accessible in static function

Comment: class base { static a(){ print basea(); }basea(){ print base}}; class derived :base{ static basea(){ print derived }} derivedobj.a();

Comment: should result print derived

Comment: @user1844112 "super is not accessible in static function" - [Oh rly?](http://ideone.com/F2x2Al) (BTW, it's neither `static` nor a function, it's a **class method.**)

Comment: static function is class method

Comment: @user1844112 You checked the link I provided? You **can** use "super" from within a class method.

Comment: yes I got it thanks for your time [[self class] classmethod ] solved problem

Comment: [[self class] classmethod ] solved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about [[super Class] getmaxrow] ?

(for a call on the derived class)

and

[[self Class] getmaxrow]

for a call on the superclass

```
- (void)display {
    NSLog(@"%d", [[self Class] getmaxrow]);
}
```

Comment: how can it work when derived class call the method

Comment: any thing similar to php static::

Comment: [super Class] on the derived class get the parent class, so [[super Class] getmaxrow] call your static method from a directly derived class instance

Comment: sorry, I didn't fully read your question, on your display method call [[self Class] getmaxrow]

Comment: yes you are right but the problem is when we override a method and using the derived class we should get the derived class method here it is getmaxrow of derived